# How can I eval a list containing symbols that are bound within a closure?

Tags: scheme

I'd like to be able to eval a list that references symbols within that closure, but I'm getting unbound variable errors.

```
(define (test x y lst)
  (eval lst)))

(test 5 3 '(+ x y))
```

I expected the `x` and `y` within the list to be bound what the `x` and `y` symbols are bound to within test; however, doing this results in an error saying `x` and `y` are unbound.

Comment: Getting `eval` to recognize lexical bindings cannot be done. The problem can be solved ni some other way so if you had an actual problem rather than a problem with a chosen solution (XY problem) we could help. I would have done `((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 5 3)` or `(apply (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) '(5 3))` or used a assoc/hash.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had already used lambda to solve the specific problem  I was working on before posting the question, I was just wondering if something like the OP could be done.

Comment: This can only be done with an eval that takes an environment. Then you can bind the names to the values in the environment that you pass to eval.

Comment: @DanD then it's not Scheme. Eg Racket has that, but it's not really lexical scope, more that you add bindings to the `eval` top level.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable names are fixed, in this case `x` and `y`, then you can also do like this:

```
(import (rnrs) (rnrs eval))

(define (test x y lst)
  (eval `(let ((x ,x) (y ,y)) ,lst)
    (environment '(rnrs))))

(test 5 3 '(+ x y))
;; -> 8
```